# Need to display mulitple records in a single row

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

In my WPF layout, the major problem is that I need the below structure in WPF. I am trying with grid but I'm not able to get the required structure as shown below.

> [image]

Please let me know what I can do so that i am able to show multiple records in one row and afterwards in a new row.

```
![<Grid Width="500" Height="400">

                <ItemsControl Name="icTodoList">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>


                         <Grid   MouseUp="Grid_MouseUp_1">

                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock  >

                                <Image Style="{DynamicResource MainTextBlock}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"  Height="60" Width="60" Source="{Binding ProjectIcon}" x:Name="imgPhoto" ></Image>

                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding ProjectTitle}" />
                                </TextBlock>
                            </Grid>


                    </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Grid>][2]
```

Comment: Did you try [WrapPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel.aspx)? There are plenty of [exapmles](http://www.dotnetperls.com/wrappanel) out there. If you need binding you can use `ListView` with `ItemsPanel` set to `WrapPanel`.

Comment: i havn't tried wrap panel do you have any code sample @icebat

Comment: Tried this not working still showing records in row::::::<WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <ItemsControl Name="icTodoList">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!--<Image  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"  Height="60" Width="60" Source="{Binding ProjectIcon}" x:Name="imgPhoto" ></Image>-->
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProjectTitle}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
            
        </WrapPanel>

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you specify the `WrapPanel` as the `ItemsPanel`, like this:

```
<ItemsControl >
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    ... Add the rest of your code here ...

</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

A wrap panel wont allow you to limit the umber of items in a row but you could use a custom control to do this. Below is a custom control I created which allows you to set a "MaxColumns" property which is reall the max number of items per row. This wrap panel will add new rows if the MaxWidth is exceeded or the MaxColumns is exceeded

```
public class ColumnLimitedWrapPanel : WrapPanel
{

    public int MaxColumns
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(MaxColsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MaxColsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxColsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MaxColumns", typeof(int), typeof(ColumnLimitedWrapPanel), new UIPropertyMetadata(5));

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        Point currentPosition = new Point();
        double ItemMaxHeight = 0.0;
        int numChildsInRow = 0;

        foreach (UIElement child in Children)
        {
            ItemMaxHeight = ItemMaxHeight > child.DesiredSize.Height ? ItemMaxHeight : child.DesiredSize.Height;

            if ((currentPosition.X + child.DesiredSize.Width > this.DesiredSize.Width) || ((numChildsInRow == MaxColumns)))
            {
                currentPosition = new Point(0, currentPosition.Y + ItemMaxHeight);
                ItemMaxHeight = 0.0;
                numChildsInRow = 0;
            }
            child.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            Rect childRect = new Rect(currentPosition, child.DesiredSize);
            child.Arrange(childRect);
            numChildsInRow++;
            currentPosition.Offset(child.DesiredSize.Width, 0);
        }
        return finalSize;
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        return base.MeasureOverride(availableSize);
    }
}
```

Then to bind it to an itemsSource use the template panel suggested by fmunkert.

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <myControls:ColumnLimitedWrapPanel MaxColumns="3" MaxWidth="120"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Below Code Works for me:

```
<Grid MouseUp="Grid_MouseUp_2">
            <ListBox  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" BorderBrush="#FFF3800C" Name="icTodoList" Background="#FFF3800C" Height="300" Width="700">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Canvas Margin="20,20,20,20" Height="200" Width="200" ClipToBounds="True" Background="#F39437" >
                        <StackPanel  Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Image  Source="{Binding ProjectIcon}"  Height="60" Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="-10,10,20,20" />
                            <TextBlock   Text="{Binding ProjectTitle}" Padding="20" Foreground="White" FontSize="26" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        </Canvas>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal"  />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
```